# How to set Custom Properties in iOS?

Tags: ios, core-data, properties, ios7

I am using Core Data and would like to run some custom code when setting a property.

```
@interface FTRecord : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic) NSTimeInterval timestamp;


@implementation FTRecord

@dynamic timestamp;

-(void)setTimestamp:(NSTimeInterval)newTimestamp
{
    //run custom code....

    //and now how to pass the value to the actual property?
    [self setTimestamp:newTimestamp];
}
```

In this case I have defined the setter body for the timestamp property. But how do I set the value of the property without running into a recursion loop?

Comment: @MartinR I don't think that's the same question -- the one you found is about dependent properties, not simply writing your own setter.

Comment: @JesseRusak: You might be right, the questions are different, but the answers are the same (or at least very similar).

Answer (score 2):

There's a magical accessor generated for each property, which in your case would be called `setPrimitiveTimestamp:` which you can use for this. Take a look at the docs for NSManagedObject's [`- (void)setPrimitiveValue:(id)value forKey:(NSString *)key`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObject/setPrimitiveValue%3aforKey%3a).

So, you want:

```
-(void)setTimestamp:(NSTimeInterval)newTimestamp
{
    //run custom code....

    //and now how to pass the value to the actual property?
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"timestamp"];
    [self setPrimitiveTimestamp:newTimestamp];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"timestamp"];
}
```

Comment: Jesse, thanks for this. This method is listed under `Methods you must NOT override` though.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You need to override the `setTimestamp:` method, as you've done, and call `setPrimitiveTimestamp:` from there.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example, which I hope will clarify.

Comment: And I've added the needed KVO stuff; I forgot NSManagedObject opts out of automatic notifications.